# How to structure MySQL db for storing multiple checkbox form data and later do statistics in php?

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

I am working on a form for storing information about the themes of the queries we receive in our company.

I am using php/MySQL to store radio button data such as:

- Name of employee
- Medium of query (e-mail/phone/in person)

With radio button data such as this, I can easily use PHP to query the database and e.g. count the numbers of queries answered by e-mail by each employee.

The trouble I am having is with data regarding the theme of the query. This is **checkbox** data with a lot of different checkboxes (50+). We would like to be able to add or remove checkboxes from time to time, though not very often.

I used to store this data just as comma-separated values in a single cell in the database and then export to excel to work with the data, but now I'd like to use another PHP form to generate statistics on the themes.

My research has lead me two to ways of doing this, that may be possible:

1. Creating a separate table in my database for my themes with one column for each possible theme, so that I'd have as many columns in my database as the number of checkboxes in my form.
2. Use the php functions serialize to store the checkbox data in one cell in my database and then later using unserialize to work with the data in php.

I am an absolute beginner, so with both options I'm unsure how I'd actually implement it:

1. With this option I am unsure whether my MySQL columns should just be "theme 1", "theme 2", etc., or whether they should have the names of my checkbox values, e.g. "money", "personal problems", "practical issues", etc. I have not been able to find a good resource on how to store the checkbox data in the right way, when the user may sometimes have clicked just 1 theme, and in other instances may have clicked 10 themes.
2. With this option I am unsure how I could populate a dropdown with unique values, and how I could later count instances of a unique value across the rows in my database.

Any help you can give me on this, including links to tutorials or questions similar to this on stackoverflow, would be much appreciated. I haven't been able to find anything about this that I could understand, other than I am thinking option 1 is probably the right way to go.

EDIT: After having received an idea about how to do this from David, I am updating my post with my attempt to understand how I would go about this.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: can try convert the form data to JSON or serialize before save into table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you're describing can be thought of as a many-to-many relationship.  You have:

- A form record, which can relate to many themes
- A theme, which can relate to many form records

In a situation like this, the *relationship itself* is a database record.  Consider this table structure:

```
FormRecords
----------
ID
SomeTitle
UserIDWhoFilledOutForm
etc.

Themes
----------
ID
ThemeName
etc.

FormRecordThemes
----------
FormRecordID
ThemeID
```

Each "primary entity" has an identifier and information about that entity.  Then there's a "linking table" which has information about the relationship between those two entities.

Any time you present a form, you simply select from the Themes to populate the check boxes.  You can add new ones as you see fit.  You probably shouldn't remove any, though you can "soft delete" them by setting some flag on the record to indicate not to display them on the form.

If you ever want to *edit* the Themes in any significant way (a way which would somehow *invalidate* previous uses of that record, such as completely changing its name/title), then keep in mind that you'd be modifying the *entire history* of its use.  I don't know if this is a risk in your domain, but in cases like that it might help to de-normalize a little bit by storing "Theme at that time" values in the relationship table.  Like, the name of the Theme at the time that relationship was created.  It's best to avoid this scenario entirely if possible, mostly by making key Theme values immutable in the domain.

---

Don't store delimited lists, don't store serialized data (unless the *entire object* really is a single data point)... Keep values separated into their own actual values in the database.  Relational databases are *really good* at querying relational data.

Comment: Thanks a lot for a helpful answer. I now know the correct way of structuring my database in relation to my form. I'll do some further research to see if I can find out how to actually implement this. If you know of a good tutorial about a case quite similar to mine (otherwise I'll have trouble putting it into practice) please let me know.

Comment: @Morten: There isn't really much to it, these are tables just like any other MySQL tables.  It's not really a question of how it's implemented, it's a question of how you think of your data.  Ideally you want to define your entities in intuitive real-life terms, and define the relationships between them.  Any time you find a relationship like this, the relationship *itself* can become an entity.  (A common example is movies and actors.  A Movie is an entity, an Actor is an entity.  The relationship between any two of them is also an entity, with a "character name" and a "salary", etc.)

Comment: I have now added 3 images to my original post, where I try to explain how this should be set up (still have little idea how to do it in practice). If you have time, could you please take a look at those images and tell me if I'm on the right track?

Comment: @Morten: It's not really clear to me what you're representing in those images.  Though `Table 2` seems pretty suspect.  I would expect a `Theme` to have an `ID` and a `Name`.  Maybe I don't understand what a "theme" is in your domain?  Is any given "theme" really a combination of those 5 values?  (money, love, employment, studies, family)

Comment: I can see that was very unclear: I didn't have one of my images there. The two bordered images are attempts to explain my 1) input form and associated MySQL-queries 2) statistics form and associated MySQL-queries. The picture in the middle is an attempt to show my SQL database structure. You should think about themes like this: I am saving data about queries answered by my employees. Each query has a number of associated themes (1 to 5 in this example). My purpose is to to measure which themes my employees receive most queries about.

Comment: @Morten: It really sounds like you're mixing up "columns" with "records" in the `Themes` table.  If "money" and "love" are different themes then they should be different *records* in that table, not different *columns*.  A table describes the structure of what something is, a record in that table represents one instance of that structure.  If you used columns to represent records then you'd have to change the table's *structure* every time someone wanted to add/modify/remove data, which isn't a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can put all values of checkboxes got from user into one CSV format string and store in one cell. Later on you can just split the string and get the values back.